How to give default value (but not zero) in number type in zod and react-hooks-form?
I'm using zod and react-hooks-form for my form. I have input field for price. To prevent uncontrolled input error we need to give defaultValues, but it forces me to give 0 for price default value. I don't want it to be zero. Can I make it an empty somehow?
import * as z from "zod";

export const ProductSchema = z.object({
  title: z.string().min(2),
  price: z.number().positive(),
  discount: z.number().int().min(0).max(100),
  ...
})

export type ProductType = z.infer<typeof ProductSchema>;

my form looks like this:
const form = useForm<ProductType>({
    resolver: zodResolver(ProductSchema),
    defaultValues: {
      title: "",
      price: 0,
      discount: 0,
      ....
    },
  });

for styling I used shadcn form components:
<FormField
                  control={control}
                  render={({ field }) => (
                    <FormItem>
                      <FormLabel>Price</FormLabel>
                      <Input
                        {...field}
                        disabled={isPending}
                        placeholder="Price of product"
                        type="number"
                        className="shadow-sm focus:ring-primary-500 focus:border-primary-500 sm:text-sm border-gray-300 rounded-md bg-white"
                      />
                      <FormMessage>{errors.price?.message}</FormMessage>
                    </FormItem>
                  )}
                  name="price"
                />



Your price requires it to be a positive number. What HTML are you using to display the price value? Perhaps this should be a https://react-hook-form.com/docs/usecontroller/controller

@Xiduzo I edited my question and added html. It is Form components from shadcn

in your zod schema
price: z
    .string()
    .min(1, 'cannot be empty')
    .default('')
    .refine(     
      (val) => !isNaN(Number(val)),
      { message: 'Invalid price' }
    )

here, it will only accept empty strings and numbers.
now you can set default value as
 defaultValues: {
      title: "",
      price: "",
      discount: 0,
      ....
    },


It worked as I expected. Now my question is does validation work if user doesn't change price (as it is "") and clicks "Save" button? Generally, I want to show empty string initially, but force to put positive number while sending a data to server

can  you check now

With this you'll get a TS error in defaultValues that number is not assignable to string.
